# Python Traceback: no error, yet no output from script

Tags: python, tar, traceback

`enter code here`Im using Eclipse with PyDev and trying to get a simple script working:

Edited Code:

```
import time
import os
import json
import tarfile
source_config='/Users/brendanryan/scripting/brendan.json'
backup_dir = '/myapp/target/'

def main():

        with open(source_config) as f:
                data = json.load(f)
                for entry in data["source_include"]:
                    #base_filename = os.path.basename(entry)
                    #source_dirs = [ name for name in os.listdir(entry) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(entry, name)) ]
                    full_dir = os.path.join(entry)
                    tar = tarfile.open(os.path.join(backup_dir, '.tar.gzip'), 'w:gz')
                    tar.add(full_dir)
                    tar.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

JSON:

```
{
    "source_type": "folder",
    "tar_type": "gzip",
    "tar_max_age": "10",
    "source_include": ["/myapp/conf", "/myapp/db"],
    "target_path": "/myapp/target"
}
```

This is SUPPOSED to work. But it doesnt. When the code was broken, I had all sorts of Tracebacks to work with... and I DO mean all. Now, I just get ""... no errors, no output, no resulting .tar.gz, no nothing when I run it.
Id be willing to try ANYTHING to get this to work right now...

For the uninitiated, this is supposed to read the json (which are variables) and use that to select the source folders, then tar.gz them and place the resulting archives in another folder. I dont know how to do it, but it would be great to actually just take ALL the folders in the "source_include", tar.gz and name it with the current date. That would be AWESOME!

Edit: Added main()... THANKS!
So, with the edit, the traceback is now:

Edit AGAIN: And NOW, no traceback. Again. No output...

Foul language is gone (Eclipse says the code is cool now)... but no output. Al all, as in no reslutant archive. Back to square one.

Comment: Show the tracebacks. There should be only one when executing the script. This is *invaluable* information.

Comment: you must use `json.load(f)` instead `json.loads(f)` (without `s`). [doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load)

Comment: Fixed the obvious errors, like the main() as per Mr Roseman, as well as the tar.add(tar) which should be tar.add(full_dir). Added new traceback. This debugging is KILLING me!

Comment: Your JSON is busted. I see a missing comma on the `"source_include"` line.

Comment: Found it, added it, same traceback :( Thanks though!

Comment: After fixing the JSON, Im back at square one. No traceback, no output. Does NOT make sense at all...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't actually seem to be calling the `main` function at all. To call a function, you need to use parentheses: `main()`.

(And you shouldn't catch an exception if all you're going to do is print a useless canned message. Better to let the exception propagate so you can see what's actually going wrong.)

Comment: Im starting to feel MORE like a newbie.. :(... Forgive me, Im teaching myself this... first REAL language since the terrible VB experience!

Comment: Exception removed, as per suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

`ValueError: Expecting , delimiter: line 6 column 2 (char 120` tells me your JSON file has an error in it.

```
JSON:
{
    "source_type": "folder",
    "tar_type": "gzip",
    "tar_max_age": "10",
    "source_include": ["/myapp/conf", "/myapp/db"], !!!COMMA GOES HERE
    "target_path": "/myapp/target"
}
```

Comment: Fixed. Was editing the wong file :( Now, I get a "Bad Operand Typ for Unary +: 'str'. Freaky!

Comment: comma and + are back to back here `tar = tarfile.open(os.path.join(backup_dir, base_filename, + '.tar.gzip'), 'w:gz')`. Your stack trace should tell you what the error is and what line it occurred on if you have any other code errors.

Comment: So, I edited, and added the new JSON and code. Now I get no traceback and no archive... Im pulling my hair out, and I dont have much!!